# How can I count the color pixels in each partition of the image

Tags: graphics, color, image

I have a image of 1000 x 1000 pixels of which I have made 5 x 5 partitions. After that I am looking for a way to count number of color pixels in each partition. Thanks in advance for help.

```
ImagePartition[I,200]//Grid
```

I got the following partitions:

[image: partition image]

Comment: Don't use `I` as a variable name.

Comment: Ok thanks for reply, I actually pasted the image in the place of I but I found pasting it here difficult so wrote I instead of the image.

Comment: No problem. You can paste the link to this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmMA6.png from your previous question. I've used that one in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
img = RemoveAlphaChannel@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmMA6.png"];
parts = ImagePartition[img, 200];

(* see the documentation here: https://wolfram.com/xid/0enzd2s6c-6u9yga *)
countColors[img_] := Module[{count = 0},
  ImageScan[If[Mean[#] != 1, count++] &, img];
  Return[count]
]

Map[countColors, parts, {2}] //Grid
```

```
16306   7574    24259   7669    16459
18185   25874   19051   26063   18207
22254   20128   17908   20212   22234
18035   25878   19046   26033   18066
16216   7063    24078   7175    16327
```

---

For colour frequencies per part, this will get you a matrix of associations that count the commonest colours appearing in each. An association contains *colour name* $\rightarrow$ *frequency* pairs. I've not used `DominantColors` because it does clustering and may return inexact colours not present in the image. Instead I've used the 32 most common colours including white as the basis for counting:

```
cols = TakeLargestBy[Tally[Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]], Last, 32];
NearestColorName = ResourceFunction["NearestColorName"];

tallycols[img_] := Association[
  (RGBColor[#] -> Count[ImageData[img], #, 2]) & /@ cols[[All, 1]]
]

partcols = Map[tallycols, parts, {2}];
```

You can then have a look at `partcols[[2, 3]]` for example:
[image: colours association]

If you need to name them you should use [`NearestColorName`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NearestColorName), use `ColorData`, or use a custom mapping as in an answer to a previous question of yours.

Comment: This finds the number of pixels in each 200x200 chunk that are not white.

Comment: Thanks for the great help and interest. This is nice to know that in first partition there are 16306 color pixels but can I find that out of these how many are for example pink, indigo, etc. and also want to include white ones also in the counts.

Comment: @AtiqueKhan I've updated the answer. You could also just change the function `countColors` here from `Mean[#] != 1` to something else like for example to search for red pixels:  `# == {1.,0.,0.}`

Answer (score 3):

```
HowManyNonWhite[i_Image] := (Times @@ ImageDimensions[i]) - 
  Count[ImageData[RemoveAlphaChannel[i]], {1., 1., 1.}, {2}]
Map[HowManyNonWhite,ImagePartition[image,200],{2}]
```

Where image is the original image.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmMA6.png"];
parts = ImagePartition[img, 200];

countWhitePixels[im_] := Length@PixelValuePositions[im, White, 0]
200^2 - Map[countWhitePixels, parts, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

A threshold for "white" sometimes is useful. Here I've set it rather high, and the counts do not change with a threshold higher than `0.9999`.  Compare with @flinty and @SHuisman, which produce slightly higher counts, to determine which method might be most appropriate.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmMA6.png"];
parts = ImagePartition[RemoveAlphaChannel[img], 200]

Map[Total[ImageData@Binarize[#, {0., 0.9999}], 2] &, parts, {2}]
```

> ```
> (*
> {{16297,  7561, 24258,  7639, 16448},
>  {18182, 25858, 19048, 26049, 18197},
>  {22249, 20105, 17885, 20182, 22225},
>  {18029, 25870, 19037, 26014, 18055},
>  {16208,  7050, 24071,  7146, 16317}}
> *)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The DominantColors function can be used to count the number of pixels of each color. However, this also includes the count for white pixels

```
imgParts = ImagePartition[i, 200];
Grid[
    DominantColors[#, All, {"Color", "Count"}] & /@ imgParts, 
    Frame -> All
]
```

Comment: One has to be careful using `DominantColors` because it does clustering. I've found that if you look at the white colour for instance and do `FullForm` on it, you'll see it is a very close white but ```RGBColor[0.9999603021318101`, 0.9999708034308904`, 0.9999640700153131`]``` is not a value that appears in the `ImageData`.

Comment: Sâu ... Thanks for the help I tried to use your method and got the following result of number of colors against each color which solved my problem much , kindly guide that how automatically mathematica can detect those number and I can further do some coputations using those number.

Comment: As @flinty has mentioned, `DominantColors` uses a clustering algorithm. From the documentation, you can see that the various methods that you can tell Mathematica to use are KMeans, KMedoids, MedianCut, MinVariance, and Octree. By default, Mathematica picks the most suitable method to generate color clusters. For the last part of your question, can you explain what sort of computations are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to sum up all the color counts that appear in all boxes one by one which manually will be difficult if the number of boxes are large such as 40000.

Comment: and yes what @flinty has mentioned about DominantColors is right but the way this is counting the colors it seems right so far.

Comment: Hi! I am facing a problem that mathematica shuts down on large output when I use ```imgParts = ImagePartition[i, 5];
Grid[
    DominantColors[#, All, {"Color", "Count"}] & /@ imgParts, 
    Frame -> All
]```  for an image of 1000 x 1000. Kindly help resolve this issue facing for long time. Thanks